# Why does .nnz indicate more non-zero elements being present in sparse matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In SciPy, I have a CSR matrix. I create a LiL matrix by choosing certain rows of each column from this matrix. Then convert resulting matrix into an CSR matrix.

I have a special case, where all rows of each column are selected. While doing this, I notice a slight perturbation of the values. Here is a MWE. It can be tried with a CSR matrix given [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XmWmBguqFCgB30K3PfmO27JXDKCC10QK).

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
ip_mat = sparse.load_npz('a_di_mat.npz')

# this is not useful for me in practice
# this is being done for comparison
lil_mat_direct = ip_mat.tolil()
csr_mat_direct = lil_mat_direct.tocsr()

# I need to copy column-by-column.
# this a MWE representing the special case where the entire column is copied
lil_mat_steps = sparse.lil_matrix((ip_mat.shape), dtype=np.float64)

for i_col in range(ip_mat.shape[1]):
    lil_mat_steps[:, i_col] = ip_mat[:, i_col]

csr_mat_steps = lil_mat_steps.tocsr()

diff_mat = csr_mat_direct - csr_mat_steps

print('nnz: direct copy: {} columnwise copy: {} diff: {}'.format(
    csr_mat_direct.nnz, csr_mat_steps.nnz, diff_mat.nnz))

# a colleague suggested the following
ind_x, ind_y = ip_mat.nonzero()

print('ip_mat: nonzero indices {} nnz {}'.format(len(ind_x), ip_mat.nnz))
```

In the first print statement, one expects:

```
nnz: direct copy: 2886100 columnwise copy: 2886100 diff: 0
```

However, one obtains:

```
nnz: direct copy: 2886100 columnwise copy: 2879757 diff: 0
```

The difference matrix being all zeros shows that the matrices are very close, if not exactly same. How to explain the reduction in the number of non-zeros? This means that non-zero values are getting perturbed. In the case of values which are very close to zero in the original matrix, they are getting perturbed and becoming zero in the output matrix. I am afraid this perturbation happens to all the non-zero elements and could affect the more general case, where only a subset of the rows are selected for each column.

For the second print statement, one obtains:

```
ip_mat: nonzero indices 2879757 nnz 2886100
```

So, could the error be in the way `.nnz` is implemented? Did the column-wise copying remove some values that are meant to be zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to follow your manipulations, but can suggest a couple of sources of differences.  Some operations (on a csr) just set data elements to 0 without removing them from the sparsity structure.  A sparse matrix stores "non-zero" elements in several arrays.  `nnz` essentially reports the size of these arrays.

Look at the code for `nonzero`

```
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask], A.col[nz_mask])
```

it does an extra `data!=0` test, so can be different from `nnz`.

`csr` also has a `eliminate_zeros` to clean up the sparsity in-place.  This operation is sufficiently expensive that `csr` does not perform it everything time you do something to the matrix.

So yes, it is possible to have a `nnz` that's larger than the `nonzero` count.  For a `csr` created from 'scratch' (ie. from a dense array, or from `coo` style inputs), `nnz` should match the `nonzero`.  But `ip_mat` was loaded from a `npz` file, with `csr` attribute arrays.  If the saved csr was not "clean", the loaded one won't be either.

## Illustration

```
In [103]: from scipy import sparse                                                                     
In [104]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[1,0,0,2],[0,3,4,0]])                                                 
In [105]: M                                                                                            
Out[105]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [106]: M.A                                                                                          
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 3, 4, 0]], dtype=int64)
In [107]: M.data                                                                                       
Out[107]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Modifying elements:

```
In [108]: M[0,1] = 12                                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:84: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
In [109]: M.data                                                                                       
Out[109]: array([ 1, 12,  2,  3,  4], dtype=int64)
In [110]: M                                                                                            
Out[110]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [111]: M.nnz                                                                                        
Out[111]: 5
In [112]: M[0,1] = 0      # data is set to 0, but indices does not change                                                                                 
In [113]: M                                                                                            
Out[113]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [114]: M.data                                                                                       
Out[114]: array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

cleaning up:

```
In [115]: M.eliminate_zeros()                                                                          
In [116]: M                                                                                            
Out[116]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

making an array from `csr` style inputs (with 0 in data):

```
In [120]: M1 = sparse.csr_matrix(([1,0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,1,2],[0,3,5]))                                    
In [121]: M1                                                                                           
Out[121]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [122]: M1.data                                                                                      
Out[122]: array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4])
In [123]: M1.nonzero()                                                                                 
Out[123]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 3, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
In [124]: M1.eliminate_zeros()                                                                         
In [125]: M1                                                                                           
Out[125]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```